# How to call multiple properties in powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$loadbalancer = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer | select Name,ResourceGroupName
```

`$loadbalancer` has two value ILB name and its resource group.
I want call both value in single PS command, Like when I call ILB name its respective resource group should be called.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't entirely clear, can you please give an example of the function being used in the next step. I used "get-command" for the examples rather than get-azurermloadbalancer to avoid being package dependent.

To get the propety from $loadbalancer you use a dot and the name.

To get the current row from pipeline you can use $_

```
$loadbalancer = Get-Command get-* | Select-Object -Property CommandType,Name

#get a particular property
$loadbalancer.CommandType

#Use both properties in one function
$loadbalancer | Where-Object{($_.CommandType -eq "function") -and ($_.Name -match "Token")}
```